# How to force Doze on Marshmallow?

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze, android-doze-and-standby

Everything seems to point to these two commands:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
```

I followed [the instructions](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) on my Nexus 6 running the Marshmallow official release. I plug in my phone to my test machine. I set up my app for testing the piece I want to test with doze. I turn off my screen. After running `battery unplug` above I get no output so I assume it works, but every time I run `deviceidle step` the output is always `Stepped to: ACTIVE`.

I'm not sure if it matters, but the particular feature of my app I'm trying to test is an alarm I'm setting that should wake the phone out of Doze. I'm wanting my device to be mid-doze when my `PendingIntent` scheduled by `AlarmManager.setAlarmClock` goes off. Could that prevent my device from entering Doze?

Comment: `setAlarmClock()` reportedly blocks Doze mode for a window of time before the event goes off.

Comment: I've seen that alarms set using `setAlarmClock()` are unaffected by Doze, but I haven't read anything about this "pre-awaking" window before the alarm goes off. Is there a link about those specifics?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33187763/115145 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110246/setexactandallowwhileidle-is-not-exact-as-of-developer-reference#comment54216992_33110418

Comment: A whole hour. Wow. As much as I believe that (no sarcasm intended, truthfully that seems to agree with my tests), it would be nice if Google had some documentation that says that.

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35914341/2826147).

Answer (score 19):

use below commands to force idle you device.

To unplug battery

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
```

You can use below commands to Force Idle state

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
or
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle enable
```

Check you are in doze more or not with below command

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle enabled
```

disable mode:

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle disable
```

Reset device battery status:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery reset
```

Answer (score 0):

The Greenify app has an experimental feature to instantly turn on Doze mode when the screen turns off.  You might need root for this however.  Greenify runs in root AND non-root modes.  Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm testing the doze mode with the ADB commands, now I accidentaly trigger this feature you've mentioned:  *instantly turn on Doze mode when the screen turns off*. I want to remove this, how can I do it?