# SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle does not wake up device

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

So I have alarm that when triggers it shows notification and sets up the same alarm with `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` for next hour, but during night, like after successfully firing alarm 1 am, 2 am, then on 3 am alarm doesn't trigger, and of course of that it doesnt shows for next hourse, because it didnt set up new ones. When i wake my device at 8:15 am, it triggers this alarm.

Android 7.0, tested on Huawei P9

Comment: paste your code in question

Comment: Doze could be to blame. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33110418/6296561)

Comment: but it is said that setExactAndAllowWhileIdle works even in doze mode, but somehow it doesn't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle - is not exact as of developer reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110246/setexactandallowwhileidle-is-not-exact-as-of-developer-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Huawei has something called Protected Apps, that can be accessed from the phone settings (Battery Manager > Protected Apps). Try adding your app to this list to keep it running after the screen is turned off.