# Alarm Manager Confusion

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to setup a Alaram below, however sometimes it fires normally and sometimes it does not and it only fires when i "open" the app. so say if alarm was schedule for 6pm, and then when i open my app at 7pm then it will fire. any ideas?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(AlarmHandler));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(AndroidApp.Context, uniqueMessageId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

AlarmManager alarmManager = AndroidApp.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;

 alarmManager.SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: have you read the docs?  There is a big red box that describes changes in this class for API 19, as well as a discussion of options to wake the device when it is asleep.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Comment: but i am using "SetExact", so it should not really matter?

Comment: "there is a big red box" and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110246/setexactandallowwhileidle-is-not-exact-as-of-developer-reference

Comment: SetAlarmClock  did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching alarmManager.SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle to alarmManager.SetAlarmClock Fixed it for me. Hope it can help someone else.

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)